# VBA Error 4065 when pasting a Chart object with more than 5 bars (works for Chart objects with less than 5 bars)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I have an Access Database with VBA that populates the series for simple chart objects and pastes them into a table into a table in a Word document.

Whenever a chart-object series contains more that five points, the paste fails with a `4065` error.

This error is:

`This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is empty or not valid.`

[image]

Charts with five or fewer points are successfully pasted into the Word document table with no error.

*The chart object is required in the Word document.  An image will not suffice.  The client needs  the ability to inspect and edit the chart data from Word.*

- The error always occurs when the `Paste` command is executed.

The source of the error is probably one of the following:

1. A corrupt `Chart` object
2. Something amiss with the destination cell in the Word table.
3. Incorrect usage of the `Paste` or `PasteSpecial` commands.
4. A combination of two or more of the above items.
5. An alternative to `Paste` or `PasteSpecial` should be used to add charts to a cell in a Word Table.

I can silence the 4065 error by placing an `On Error Resume` Next above the call to `Paste`.

```
            On Error Resume Next
            .Cell(TblRow, 2).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
                                                DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
                                                Placement:=wdInLine, _
                                                DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

This allows the Word document generation to complete.

- Charts with 1 to 5 data points are pasted into the Word table without any problem.

  [image]
- Charts with more than 6 data points are not.  The paste generates a 4065 error.

  [image]

I am not sure why charts with six or more data points cause a 4065 error on the Paste.

### What I am trying:

1. Inspected and queried the series in the `Chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet` for charts with six or more data points.  The series seem to be in good shape and no data is missing.
2. Adding some API calls to VBA to programmatically get the clipboard contents following the Paste.  If the chart object from the clipboard is in tact, the problem lies with the Word table cell.

### What I have tried thus far:

1. I tried a 3-second pause and a 5-second pause followed by a `DoEvents` after the `Copy`. This had no effect.  Charts with 5 or fewer data points are pasted into the Word Table.  Charts with more than 5 data points throw the 4065 error.
2. Added a method to inspect the data being added to the chart.  Nothing looks suspicious.  The data looks good.

I am interested to hear any recommendations or suggestions on this problem.

### Source Code

The MS Word Document being generated uses another MS Word Document as a template.  The template Word document contains a table that has ten charts. The ten charts are clustered bar (xlBarClustered) charts.  The first template chart has a data series with 1 data point, the second template chart has a data series with 2 data points, etc. The tenth chart has a data series with ten data points.

The template charts are loaded into an array: `chtArray`.

```
' This sub initializes ChtArray.  Each index corresponds to the number of rows in the chart
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub InitCharts()

    Dim ProgCnt As Integer, ChrtCnt As Integer
    
    ProgCnt = 0
    ChrtCnt = 0

    ' Initialize an array of chart references to each chart in ChartTemplate.docx
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Do While ProgCnt < SrcDoc.InlineShapes.Count And ChrtCnt < MAXCHARTS
    
        ProgCnt = ProgCnt + 1
        
        If SrcDoc.InlineShapes(ProgCnt).Type = wdInlineShapeChart Then
        
            ChrtCnt = ChrtCnt + 1
            Set ChtArray(ChrtCnt) = SrcDoc.InlineShapes(ProgCnt).Chart
            
        End If
        
    Loop

End Sub
```

As the target Word Document is generated, the following code adds a copy of a chart from the template for the number of data points from the `ChtArray` and adds it to the target Word Document.

```
' This sub adds the charts and WrkGrp percentages to the table
'-------------------------------------------------------------
Sub AddChartsToTable(TblRowCnt)

    Dim TblRow As Integer, DesTblRowCnt As Integer, clipFormats As Integer
    Dim currentWorkGroup As Double
    
    currentWorkGroup = rstFiltered.Fields("Work Group").Value

    With tbl
    
        For TblRow = 3 To TblRowCnt ' Header and column heads are in rows 1 and 2
            
                ' WorkGroup column formatting and value
                '--------------------------------------
            With .Cell(TblRow, 1).Range
            
                '========================================================
                ' TODO: Remove the Q and WG
                '========================================================
                .Text = Format(rstFiltered![WrkGrpPct].Value, "##0%") & _
                        " Q" & CStr(rstFiltered![QNum].Value) & _
                        " WG:" & CStr(rstFiltered.Fields("Work Group").Value)
                
                Select Case rstFiltered![WrkGrpPct].Value
                    Case Is >= 0.75
                    .Font.TextColor = ColorGreen
                    
                Case Is >= 0.6
                    .Font.TextColor = ColorGold
                    
                Case Else
                    .Font.TextColor = ColorRed
                    
                End Select
                
            End With
            
            currentWorkGroup = rstFiltered.Fields("Work Group").Value
            DesTblRowCnt = GetNumChtPoints(rstFiltered![Work Group])
          
            ' Set reference to the only chart we're updating,
            ' the one in SrcDoc with the correct number of rows
            '--------------------------------------------------
            If ChtArray(DesTblRowCnt) Is Nothing Then
                ' TODO: Log the instance...
            Else
            
                Set Cht = ChtArray(DesTblRowCnt)
                ' Set Cht = NewChart()
                Set Pts = Cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points
                Set sht = Cht.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet
               
                ' Inspect the chart series before setting the points.
                InspectChartSeries
                                
                UpdateChartForWrkGrp DesTblRowCnt, TblRow
                
                ' Inspect the chart series after setting the points.
                InspectChartSeries

                ' Paste the chart object into the Word table.
                Cht.Copy
                Pause 2
                                                              
                ' Check the clipboard contents (Did the copy move the chart to the clipboard?)
                
                
                On Error Resume Next
                .Cell(TblRow, 2).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
                                                    DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
                                                    Placement:=wdInLine, _
                                                    DisplayAsIcon:=False
                
            End If
          
            If TblRow < TblRowCnt Then tbl.Rows.Add
          
        Next TblRow
    
  End With
  
End Sub
```

The `UpdateChartForGrp` method sets the data for the newly added chart ad sets the color for each bar.

```
' This sub's purpose is to update the chart with the appropriate data point name and color.
' Called from AddChartsToTable
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub UpdateChartForWrkGrp(TotChtPts As Integer, TblRow As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ptCount As Integer
       
    ' Update the chart data itself
    '-----------------------------
    For i = 2 To TotChtPts + 1
    
        sht.Range("A" & i) = rstFiltered!Department.Value
        sht.Range("B" & i) = rstFiltered![DeptPct].Value ' Chart template cells formatted as a percentage already
        
        ' While we are updating chart, add Change data to the Word table
        '---------------------------------------------------------------
        tbl.Cell(TblRow, 3).Range.InsertBefore rstFiltered!Change.Value & IIf(i = 2, "", vbCr)
        rstFiltered.MoveNext
        
    Next i
    
    Cht.Refresh
    
    ptCount = 0
      
    For Each Pt In Pts
    
        Select Case Val(Pt.DataLabel.Caption) / 100
            Case Is >= 0.75
                Pt.Interior.Color = ColorGreen
            Case Is >= 0.6
                Pt.Interior.Color = ColorGold
            Case Else
                Pt.Interior.Color = ColorRed
        End Select
        
        ptCount = ptCount + 1
        
    Next Pt
    
    Debug.Print "UpdateChartForWrkGrp:ptCount = " & ptCount
    
    Cht.Refresh ' just to be on the safe side
      
End Sub
```

### Example Data

Data for the referenced `rstFiltered` Recordset are below.

| Work Group | Department | DeptPct | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.7 | 0.05 |
| 1 | B | 0.6 | 0.07 |
| 1 | C | 0.8 | 0.00 |
| 1 | D | 0.4 | 0.00 |
| 1 | E | 0.9 | 0.10 |
| 1 | F | 0.8 | 0.05 |

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but I have found https://freeclipboardviewer.com/ to be very useful to inspect complex clipboard contents. Compare the contents of 5 vs. 6 bars.

Comment: Also it might be useful to see more of your code: how and what do you copy before paste?

Comment: Try giving your system some time to copy to the clipboard, maybe add `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")): Do Events` after the copy line.

Comment: Not enough code to reproduce issue. Provide sample data as text table.

Comment: Tried a 3 second pause and a 5 second pause after the copy.  No effect - but worth the try.

Comment: I have no problem manually copy/paste chart with more than 5 data points. Need to provide your code as well as sample data.

Comment: Source code added on 2-Oct-2021.

Comment: No sample data? Where is rstFiltered declared and set? This is still not a reproducible process. This code is in Access and it pulls data from Excel to build chart and paste into Word?

Comment: June7 - yes, this code is in Access  and it pulls data from Excel to build chart and paste into Word.  It actually opens a Word document that has a table with 10 charts for with 1....10 data points.  This is the contents of ChtArray.  I would really like to programmatically create a new chart and insert it into the Word table row in the destination document using a method other than copy and paste.  I have added some example data for the rstFiltered fields above.  I wrote a new function to instantiate a new chart.  I need to research a method other than paste to put the chart in the table.